# $f$ is bounded on $E$ and the sequence is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose ${f_n(x)}$ is a sequence of bounded functions that converges uniformly to $f$
on $E$.

Prove that $f$ is bounded on $E$ and that the sequence is uniformly bounded,
i.e.,

$sup_{n}$
$sup_{x\in E}$
$|f_n(x)| < ∞$.

I am done with this proof but my final step looks like $|f_n(x)| <M$ where $M$ is the maximum of all $M_n's$ .

How to finish my proof?  Just take supremum?
Thank you!

Comment: What is $\sup \sup |f_n(x)|$??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam, I have corrected the original problem

Comment: What are $M_n$'s and why does their maximum exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $E$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq N$,
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 1
$$

for all $x\in E$. Since the particular function $f_N$ is bounded and the inequality also holds for it, we have that for every $x\in E$,
$$
|f(x)| \leq 1 + \sup_{x\in E}|f_N(x)| = M <\infty,
$$

which means that
$$
\sup_{x\in E}|f(x)| \leq M < \infty,
$$

so $f$ is bounded. To show the sequence is uniformly bounded, notice that if $n\geq N$,
$$
|f_n(x)| \leq 1+ |f(x)|
$$

for all $x\in E$. Then, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, take
$$
|f_n(x)| \leq \max\{\sup_{x\in E}|f_1(x)|,\ldots,\sup_{x\in E}|f_{N-1}(x)|,M\} = L
$$

Since the left hand side doesn't depend on $n$ or $x\in E$, we get
$$
\sup_{x\in E}\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|f_n(x)| \leq L < \infty.
$$